# CAML Query with many conditions

Tags: 2010, caml

I would like to know, is there a way to build such a CAML Query, or is this nonsense:

I have a SharePoint List with two ContentTypes: `ServiceGroup` and `Services`. 
The Fields are

1. Title
2. ServiceGroup [MultiLookup to Service]
3. Service[Lookup to ServiceGroup]
4. Responsible[Person]

A `ServiceGroup` can contain many `Services`. For ServiceGroups and Services many Persons could be responsible.

For this given list I want to select with a `CAML Query` all ListItems of `ContentType ServiceGroup` for which person `'ABC'` is responsible AND `all Services`, which are `"Children"` of the `ServiceGroups`, selected within the first Query part, regardless of whether person 'ABC' or someone else is responsible for them.

Comment: Hi, I can build a CAML Query with one or more WHERE conditions( with u2u caml query builder) without error, but I don't know how I can use the result of the first query part(ListItems of Type ServiceGroup) in the second part(Services which are Children of the given ServiceGroups).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the server object model? If so, try to use SPMETAL. With this in mind you are able to query your context with Linq.
When building large queries i think this is the most useful way.